# Object Initialization pattern

Tags: delphi, oop, design-patterns, initialization

This question is OOP-patterns related (but i'm working with delphi IDE).
I'm developing a library that needs a sort of memory management on their objects (without garbage collection nor reference counting).
I'm thinking on making initialization/finalization methods public to the users knowing that construction/destruction methods will be called automatically (allowing users to clean the object memory without destroying the object for instance). Is there a similar pattern or best practices recommended to do this?

```
type
  TAbstractInitializable = abstract class(TAbstractBase)
  constructor Create();
  destructor Destroy(); override;
  private
    FInitialized: Boolean;
  protected
    procedure CheckError();
    procedure DoInitialize(); virtual; abstract;
    procedure DoFinalize(); virtual; abstract;
  public
    procedure Initialize();
    procedure Finalize();
  end;

  //...

  procedure TAbstractInitializable.CheckError();
  begin
    if not FInitialized then
      raise Exception.Create('Error: Trying to use a non initialized object.');
  end;

  procedure TAbstractInitializable.Create();
  begin
    inherited;
    DoInitialize();
  end;

  procedure TAbstractInitializable.Destroy();
  begin
    DoFinalize();
    inherited;
  end;

  procedure TAbstractInitializable.Initialize();
  begin
    if not FInitialized then begin
      DoInitialize();
      FInitialized:=True;
    end;
  end;

  procedure TAbstractInitializable.Finalize();
  begin
    if FInitialized then begin
      DoFinalize();  
      FInitialized:=False;
    end;
  end;
```

So this could be a library non abstract class:

```
type
  TDataModel = class(TAbstractInitializable)
  private
    FDataList: TList;
  protected
    procedure DoInitialize(); override;
    procedure DoFinalize(); override;
  public
    procedure DoSomethingWithData();  
  end;

//...

procedure TDataModel.DoInitialize();
begin
  FDataList:=TList.Create();
  LoadData(FDataList); //for non emptyness in this example
end;

procedure TDataModel.DoFinalize();
begin
  FreeData(FDataList); //for no memory leaks in this example
  FDataList.Destroy();
end;

procedure TDataModel.DoSomethingWithData();
begin
  CheckError();
  //Do something here
end;
```

Comment: I'm trying to allow manual and automatic memory management for the parent classes (in order to achieve a library implementation requirement).

Comment: Initialize and Finalize are really for the whole unit, not individual classes.

Comment: There is no need to create a `DoInitialize` and `DoFinalize` methods. There are already methods called `AfterConstruction` and `BeforeDestruction` for this type of thing.

Comment: Is it not enough to have a `Clear` method? If memory was allocated, it is restored to a fresh state. Compare with `TStringList` for example.

Comment: @Ron: `initialization` and `finalization`sections of a unit are unit-wide.There are system routines called `Initialize` and `Finalize` and these work on individual records. But nothing prevents you from using these names as method names of a class (hierarchy).

Comment: If you only want to be able to reset an object, then give it a `Reset` or `Clear` method for that. But if you want to be able to do more, then I agree with @GrayMatter: use `AfterConstruction` and `BeforeDestruction`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Delphi, but I think having public methods for initializing and deinitializing objects is the right way to go. For example in any sort of file stream object you'll usually see an `open()` and `close()` method. Although they're not always automatically called, it gives the client the ability to manage those behaviors explicitly instead of relying on the class to implicitly initialize and cleanup after itself. In the case of a file handle, you don't want to couple releasing a file handle to garbage collection because garbage collection is often difficult to predict.

I would not make your `initialize()` and `finalize()` methods public. If the language was designed for these methods to be used by clients, they would already be public, and in all the libraries I've used, I've never seen something like that. I would write two differently named methods that are descriptive of the action your performing (e.g. `create()` & `destroy()`). Your `initialize()` and `finalize()` may invoke these methods respectively.